# Issues extracting features from nasnetlarge model - keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to extract some image features through pre trained NASNet model using python keras. I am also trying to dump the extracted features to .mat file. Below is my script. 
When I try to run this program, I get the error

```
ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 532 layers into a model with 526 layers
```

If I use the same program to extract features using InceptionV3 model, it works fine. Can someone please tell me how to fix this issue?

```
from keras.applications.nasnet import NASNetLarge
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import decode_predictions
import os

from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
import csv
import scipy.io
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle

model = NASNetLarge(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

[error log (screen shot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qjaq.png)

Comment: Since your error pops up at `model = NASNetLarge(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)`, the rest of your code after that is redundant (removed); see why [a wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)

Comment: There seem to be still open issues with loading the NASNetLarge model in Keras - see [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10109) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10138).

Comment: thanks @desertnaut